# add different colour to bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I constructed the following plot using `ggplot` using the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Variable, y=Value, fill=Yield.Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image: Resulting plot]

I had two questions:

1) How do I change the colour of the bar: I want to colour the pink bar as white and blue bar as grey with black borders. If in the code, I use `col="White",fill="White"`, it colours both of them with the same colour and also stacks them up on each other

2) For each bar, I have the standard error in separate vector

```
 For pink bars, se1<-c(0.08,0.07,0.08,0.07)
 For blue bars, se2<-c(0.07,0.1,0.06,0.06)
```

I wanted to know how to add this standard errors to resepctive batch

How do I add this to the bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide data it is much easier to answer. Here I have created a new set.

1. I have included martin's answer for the color
2. If you have a se value per bar, your should directly add it inside your data frame and use 
   [geom_errorbar()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_errorbar.html). Check documentation for more info.

.

```
Variable <- factor(c("VAr1","VAr1","Var2","Var2","Var3","Var3","VAr4","VAr4"))
Yield.Type <- factor(c('O','R','O','R','O','R','O','R'))
Value <- c(1,2,3,4,3,5,6,5)
se1<-c(0.08,0.07,0.08,0.07,0.1,0.06,0.1,1)
data <- data.frame(Variable,Yield.Type,Value,se1)
limits <- aes(ymax = Value + se1, ymin=Value - se1)
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.8)

ggplot(data, aes(x=Variable, y=Value,fill=Yield.Type,colour=Yield.Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","black")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "grey"))+
  geom_errorbar(limits, position=dodge,width=0.1)
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Answer (score 0):

First question: use `scale_color_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` (see [add different colour to bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083760/add-different-colour-to-bar-plot/25084342#25084342))

```
p <- ggplot(...)
p + scale_color_manual(values=c("white","black")) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "grey"))
p
```

Second qestion: Look [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_%28ggplot2%29/#bar-graphs) or [R: ggplot2 barplot and error bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064462/r-ggplot2-barplot-and-error-bar) for help.