# R bar graphs with error bars

Tags: r, graph, standard-error

I am relatively new to R and have been trying to figure out how I can add error bars to my bar graphs. To use a simple example, I have prevalence data of bacteria for two years that I'm hoping to add error bars to. To start, I create a data frame with x and y values as well as standard error with a 95% confidence interval:

```
>df<-data.frame(Year=factor(c(2011,2012)),MS_Prevalence=c(16.02,7.08),se=c(.20750,.10325))
```

I then set the upper and lower limits for the error bars:

```
>limits<-aes(ymax=MS_Prevalence+se,ymin=MS_Prevalence-se)
```

Next, I set my graph as p:

```
>p<-ggplot(df,aes(y=MS_Prevalence,x=Year))
```

Now I will add the bars to the graph:

```
>p+geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

I select the width of my bars:

```
>dodge<-position_dodge(width=0.9)
```

Then, attempt to add error bars:

```
>p+geom_bar(position=dodge)+geom_errorbar(limits,position=dodge,width=0.25)
```

When I add my error bars, my graph turns from bar to line. While it does include the error bars, I need a bar graph to appropriately represent my data. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064462/r-ggplot2-barplot-and-error-bar ? Google also seems to give a number of hints eg http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/  http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-barplot-with-ggplot2/

Comment: Why did you remove `stat = "identity"` from `geom_bar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(df) + 
geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=MS_Prevalence), stat='identity', color=gray)+
geom_errorbar(aes(x=Year, ymin=(MS_Prevalence-se),ymax=(MS_Prevalence+se)),
   width=0.25)
```

[image]