# ggplot, barplot with error bar: two binary columns and one categorical

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data, errorbar

Dear Stackoverflow members,

I have a dataset consisting of the following: one column `lang` containing five different languages. two other columns `CAN` and `INT` containing either (0, 1). You can see the data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1phjnQNsSawpbX-7TSCVcjWsqHuMAWu14W4RwnCSccFk/edit#gid=0)

I would like to plot two bars per language, one for `CAN== 0` and the other for `CAN==1`. The y axis should be the row counts of `INT` (or `INT==1`). I would like these bars to have error bar on them. Some post suggested use `melt()` in order to convert the format to a long one. However, that does not see to work since my data are continuous.

Comment: You might want to check these links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064462/r-ggplot2-barplot-and-error-bar
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4d-qUTTY44

Comment: @AliAlshehri, OK, no more distractions here. Ive updated my answer - hopefully this will meet your needs. Also, for future questions please look at the advice on how to post a reproducible question, then help will come quicker and more likely correct.

Comment: @user127649 this is perfect. Thank you so much. there is one small concern, which is the measure of the y-axis, which I am having a hard time to interpret in the produced graph. I originally wanted it to represent counts or (better) percentage of trials.

Comment: The y-axis currently shows proportion, so just multiply by 100 to concert to percentage. One other point - the function I wrote is a bit crude. There are ways to adjust the CI to increase accuracy. It is simple to modify the function to fix both these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I had a look at `stat_summary` last night, and maybe it works, but I couldn't do it. So I still think `geom_errorbar` is the way to go, as first suggested.

First, to calculate the CI I wrote a function. There may be one built in, but I don't know it.

```
BinCI <- function(x) {
     p <- mean(x)
     s <- sqrt(p * (1 - p) / length(x))
     i <- s * 2
     i
}
```

Second the data manipulation:

```
df2 <- unite(df, uLang, c(Lang, CAN), remove = FALSE) %>%  # Create the groups
     group_by(Lang, uLang) %>%
     summarize(prop = mean(INT), ci = BinCI(INT))  # Calculate the mean and CI using the `BinCI` function


Lang  uLang       prop         ci
Ar    Ar_0    0.07200000   0.04623972
Ar    Ar_1    0.44406780   0.05785682
Kic   Kic_0   0.16000000   0.06558048
Kic   Kic_1   0.44745763   0.05789989
Sp    Sp_0    0.04968944   0.03425168
Sp    Sp_1    0.24390244   0.04742311
Yuc   Yuc_0   0.16800000   0.06687923
Yuc   Yuc_1   0.40780142   0.05852797
Zap   Zap_0   0.15151515   0.06241559
Zap   Zap_1   0.26785714   0.04831810
```

Third, the plot:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(uLang, prop, fill = Lang)) +
     geom_col() +
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = prop - ci, ymax = prop + ci), width = 0.3) +
     guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @user127649. that is exactly what i was looking for. Now I would like to add error bars?

Comment: Hi @AliAlshehri, I don't know what sort of error bars you need? If you can calculate the type you want, and put them in a dataframe, you can add them using this `geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ?, ymax = ?), width = 0.2)'. Unfortunately I'm done for tonight, but I will be back tomorrow evening

Comment: Thank you. Here is what i was looking for done in SPSS [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mBmueQ07fTda6ev_6hc48gMGu1AJOE7kvIjmNITipIE/edit].

Comment: I guess the trouble that I am having is more technical: how to get the error and match it to its respective group. Were you able to calculate the error in R? Also I know n refers to the number of values in each group but I am not sure how did you get it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AliAlshehri, The example I posted shows how to match the error to the groups. As for calculating them... how are they calculated? I mean, what sort of error are you trying to show?

Comment: thank you. I am trying to calculate error based on the 95% CI.

Comment: i was hoping I can do that using stat_summary()

Comment: Here is my full code:
Lang-data_long <- unite(df2, u, c(Lang, CAN), remove = FALSE)
langPlot = ggplot(Lang_data_long, aes(u, INT, fill= Lang))
langPlot+ stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom= "bar")'