# How to manually add an error bar (95% CI) to a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I drew a cumulative barplot with ggplot2:

```
a <- ggplot(datasilice2) +
  aes(x = Duree_exposition_4gpes, fill = factor(Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", show.legend = F, colour = "NA", alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(NA, "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Yes", limits=c(0,0.5),oob = rescale_none, breaks = seq(0,0.5,0.05), labels = percent_format(suffix = "%", accuracy = 1))
```

It looks like this:
[image: barplot without error bar]

I want to add an error bar for each column.

So first, I manually calculated each 95% CI :

```
binom.test(2,45)$conf.int*100 
binom.test(3,10)$conf.int*100 
binom.test(5,18)$conf.int*100 
binom.test(12,27)$conf.int*100
```

Then, I use the geom_errorbar function:

```
a + geom_errorbar(ymin=0.2, ymax=0.4,width = 0.2, size=1)
```

It does draw an error bar, but every error bars is the same:
[image: same error bar]

Right now I am stuck: I was not able to find the solution for setting every error bar manually. I imagined something like this, but it won't work:

```
a + geom_errorbar(ymin=c(0.2,0.22,0.23,0.30), ymax=c(0.4,0.43,0.35,0.50))
#random number, I will put CI here
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): ymin, ymax
```

Any ideas of what to do to get something like this? [image: (done with paint)]
Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the 10 first rows of my database (datasilice2):

```
> dput(head(datasilice2, 10))
structure(list(Duree_exposition_4gpes = c(3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 3), Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

As suggested, I created a new dataframe and tried to feed that into the geom_errorbar:

```
a <- ggplot(datasilice2) +
  aes(x = Duree_exposition_4gpes, fill = factor(Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", show.legend = F, colour = "NA", alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(NA, "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Yes", limits=c(0,0.5),oob = rescale_none, breaks = seq(0,0.5,0.05), labels = percent_format(suffix = "%", accuracy = 1))

newdf <- data.frame(xcol=c(0,1,2,3),ymincol=c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),ymaxcol=c(0.25,0.30,0.45,0.5))
a + geom_errorbar(data=newdf,aes(x=xcol,ymin=ymincol,ymax=ymaxcol))
```

But here is a new error:

```
Error in factor(Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200) : 
  object 'Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200' not found
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(datasilice2)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(datasilice2, 20))`.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064462/r-ggplot2-barplot-and-error-bar) and also [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/building-barplots-with-error-bars/).

Comment: done, see first post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will add the error bars in a percentage scale.

In the two middle bars the error bars one goes up to 100% and the other starts at 0%, because all data points for each of those groups were 1 or 0, respectively. With actual data this will probably change.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

datasilice2 %>%
  group_by(Duree_exposition_4gpes) %>%
  summarise(N = n(),
            Sum = sum(Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200),
            LimInf = binom.test(Sum, N)$conf.int[1],
            LimSup = binom.test(Sum, N)$conf.int[2],
            Sum = Sum/N) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Duree_exposition_4gpes, y = Sum,
             fill = factor(Sum))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = position_dodge(), show.legend = FALSE, 
           colour = NA, alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep("red", 4)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LimInf, ymax = LimSup,
                    width = 0.2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Yes",
                     limits=c(0, 1),
                     oob = rescale_none, 
                     breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.05), 
                     labels = percent_format(suffix = "%", accuracy = 1))
```

[image]

If you want to have each bar with its own colour you can do

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue"))
```

As for the `summarise` function, it executes the following steps:

1. `N = n()` - get the number of rows
2. `Sum = sum(Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200)` - sum the `1`s, the size of the bars
3. `LimInf` and `LimSup` - function `binom.test` needs the total data size (`N`) and the number of successes (`Sum`). This is why the proportion is only computed in the next code line.
4. `Sum = Sum/N` - compute the proportion of successes.

Comment: Yes, this is it but with relative frequency : I don't want to add error bar but the 95% confidence interval of this relative frequency of "yes"

Comment: This is exactly what I expect! I guess... because I am getting this new error: ```Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors```... does it have something to do with the fact that Y (antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200) is coded ```as.factor``` ?

Comment: @B_slash_ Yes, convert to numeric with `as.numeric(as.character(antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200))`.

Comment: @B_slash_ I would do that before `group_by`. Something like `mutate(antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200 = as.numeric(etc))`.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I did not need ```mutate...```, in fact I just switched my Y axis to as.numeric and it worker! If you have some more time, can you explain me your code (summerize function)? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your manually calculated data into a data frame and feed that into the `geom_errorbar`.  I don't think `ggplot` accepts vectors. So your new data frame, say `newdf`, should have columns for the x value, the y min value, and the ymax value.  Then something like this should work: `a + geom_errorbar(data=newdf,aes(x=xcol,ymin=ymincol,ymax=ymaxcol))` (the column names need to match whatever you decide to name them in the dataframe).

Comment: I created the dataframe (not sure if it is done well) but I have another error (reported in first post)

Comment: @B_slash_ try `geom_errorbar(data=newdf,aes(x=xcol,ymin=ymincol,ymax=ymaxcol),inherit.aes=FALSE)` ...I'll admit I haven't run your code with your update sample data so this is just off the top of my head.  But I think the error is due to the fact that `newdf` doesn't contain the column you used for fill in your main `a` plot.  Looks like you may have some other answers available to you now, too.

Comment: thanks, but i am still getting the same error: ```Error in factor(Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200) : 
  object 'Antinucléaires_sup_ou_egal_200' not found```